# ServiceProvider eating my battery after SIM unlocking

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, sim-unlocking

I had my Samsung Galaxy S3 SIM unlocked last week. It runs a rooted Android 4.1.2. Since then, I've noticed that ServiceProvider is consuming much more battery that I have ever noticed before. Can SIM-unlocking a phone lead to a higher battery consumption from ServiceProvider, and if so why?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.